# Check all properties are not null in n-depth POJO

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, pojo

I am needing a function that takes any object and returns true/false if every child meets a condition. Currently that condition is that the property is truthy. So null and undefined should return false, but a value of false is a pass.

The project I'm working in is in Typescript, but this applies to vanilla JS as well, and I am also able to use lodash.

I've started with this function so far:

```
function CheckAllPropertiesDefined(obj){
  if (!obj) {
    return false;
  }

  for (const key in obj) {
    if (o[key] === null || o[key] === undefined) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

However the requirements of what I'm doing changed (no longer a flat object) and I realised it's not working for nested properties.

The outcome of running it against this object is true, when it shouldn't be:

```
const obj = {
  prop1: true,
  prop2: true,
  prop3: {
    prop3a: false,
  },
  prop4: {
    test: null,
    foo: false,
    child: {
      child2: null,
    },
  },
};
```

It should return false because `prop4.test` and `prop4.child.child2` are null. I am figuring some recursion is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally prefer to split apart the traversal of the object from the action we perform on it.  Here, I would write a generic function that can apply a predicate against any (scalar) node, and recurses on objects or arrays.  Then we can simply call it with a function that tests that the node is not `null` or `undefined` to get back a function to use in testing an object.  This is an example:

```js
const checkAllDeep = (pred) => (xs) =>
  Array .isArray (xs)
    ? xs .every (x => checkAllDeep (pred) (x))
  : xs && typeof xs == 'object'
    ? Object .entries (xs) .every (([k, v]) => checkAllDeep (pred) (v))
  : pred (xs)

const checkAllPropertiesDefined = checkAllDeep (x => x !== null && x !== undefined)

const obj = {prop1: true, prop2: true, prop3: {prop3a: false}, prop4: {test: null, foo: false, child: {child2: null}}}

console .log (checkAllPropertiesDefined (obj))
```

Later if we want to change the predicate (we want to accept `null` but not `undefined`, for instance), it's easy to find.  And we could write other functions such as `const allPropsAreStrings (checkAllDeep ((x) => typeof x == 'string')` quite simply.

Comment: That makes sense. My specific use case didn't call for something like that, and maybe it's a bit more complex than I would need as opposed to just calling a function and passing an object.

Comment: @NattyMan0007: I would argue that it's *simpler* than many alternatives.  And in the end, we create a function that we use by passing an object: `checkAllPropertiesDefined (obj)`.  But we do it atop a reusable function.

Answer (score 0):

So 30 seconds into this post I got out a drawing utensil (iPad) and wrote down the logical steps to solve this problem and found a solution. I highly recommend doing this when stuck instead of running to the internet.

I wasn't able to find a suitable solution to this specific problem on SO, all the solutions were just for non-nested POJOs.

If anyone can improve it I'm open to that.

Here is my solution in Javscript:

```
function CheckAllPropertiesDefined(obj) {
  if (!obj) {
    return false;
  }

  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
        if (!CheckAllPropertiesDefined(obj[key])) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      if (obj[key] === null || obj[key] === undefined) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```